# How add external resource folder on JBoss7?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

Following matter is JBossAS 7.1 Developer Guider:

> Change ResourceBundle location In previous versions of AS, the
>   JBOSS_HOME/server//conf/ was available in the classpath.
>   Hence the properties files in that location were available in the
>   classpath of the application.
>
> In AS7, to get those properties available in the classpath, package
>   them within your application. For example, if you are deploying a .war
>   then package those properties in WAR WEB-INF/classes/ folder. If you
>   want those properties accessible to all components in a .ear, then
>   package them at the root of some .jar and place that jar in EAR lib/
>   folder.

But this method is not so good if there are too many resource files, we can't package all resource file to jar or ear.

For the new class loading method - module. I try following method:

> create module.xml file .. you will chose module name... for instnace
>   custom.myconfig
>
> ```
> <resources>
>     <resource-root path="."/>
>     <!-- Insert resources here -->
> </resources>
>
> <dependencies>     
> </dependencies> </module>   In your jboss-deployment-structure.xml include this module to your app
> <jboss-deployment-structure>
> <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
> <deployment>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="custom.myconfig/>
>     </dependencies>
>     <resources>
>     </resources>
> </deployment>
>
> <sub-deployment name="My_WAR.war">
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="custom.myconfig" />
>     </dependencies>
> </sub-deployment>
> ```

https://community.jboss.org/message/723631

But I found you can't set absolute path to path, like: [resource-root path=""C:\resourcefolder"].

That's means you also need include all resource files on JBossAS 7.

It is very simple on JBossAS 5.x-6.x, only need add folder path like "C:\resourcefolder" to classpath is OK. But its like an impossible mission on JBossAS7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I soft link resource folder to JBossAS 7.....

Linux:

```
In -s
```

Windows:

```
MKLINK /D
```

or

```
Junction.exe
```